# Bounty Option Not Available - Am I missing something?

Tags: support, bounty

I have a question that has only had 13 views over 3 days. I was going to give it a bounty to try to increases views on it but there is no option to do so. Do I have to wait longer for this to become available (I thought 2 days was standard), or do I need a larger reputation than 71 to offer a bounty? I saw another thread that you needed 2* if offering it on the same question but I haven't bountied this question before... or is this something else all together?

My question is: [Servername Secure Connection - Loose Match](https://serverfault.com/questions/836861/servername-secure-connection-loose-match)

Comment: I read you question a couple of days ago and again today. I got bored part way through and still don't really know what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're almost there, [the limit for offering bounties on your questions is 75 reputation points](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/set-bounties). Just a few more, and you're set.

Comment: Oh, thanks, skipped right over the `Awarded At: 75 Reputation` part.